# 'file not found' when trying to get gridFS file from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am trying to read my files that I uploaded to mongodb and Im getting `file not found` each time , when clearly there is file with the name Im trying to find in my database. I used [this](http://niralar.com/mongodb-gridfs-using-mongoose-on-nodejs/) method for implementing `gridfs`

CODE:

```
    let mongoose = require('mongoose');
    let gridfs = require('gridfs-stream');

    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://foo123.mlab.com:123456/db_name', {
        auth: {
          user: 'username',
          password: 'password'
        }
      })
      .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    gridfs.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    let connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

connection.once('open', () => {
    var gfs = gridfs(connection.db);
    router.post('/' ,(req, res) => {
        gfs.exist({ filename: '6866866-Tue-May-29-2018.jpg' }, function (err, file) {
            if (err || !file) {
                console.log(err)
                res.send('File Not Found');
            } else {
                let readstream = gfs.createReadStream({ filename: '6866866-Tue-May-29-2018.jpg' });
                readstream.pipe(res);
            }
        });
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

file from db that im trying to get:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b0d2xxxxxxxxxx14cfb118"
    },
    "length": 641142,
    "chunkSize": 261120,
    "uploadDate": {
        "$date": "2018-05-29T10:39:37.568Z"
    },
    "md5": "c9bc6d74axxxxxxxxxxxx25a70",
    "filename": "6866866-Tue-May-29-2018.jpg",
    "contentType": "image/jpeg"
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what gets piped to the console log? What does "err" contain?

Comment: `null` there is no error , only response with `File Not Found `

Comment: "File Not Found" is your message. The logic that got you there I think is wrong. My Javascript is rusty, but I don't think you can successfully determine if 'err' is null or not like that. Happy to be wrong though.

Comment: can you explain? the function says basically , if there is no `file` object, or there is an error along the way, send `File Not Found` pretty straight forward

Comment: Try re-writing the function as: if(!file){ console.log(err)...} else { ....} and see how that goes

Comment: nope, same result :(

Comment: Ignoring the If/Else logic, does it actually work when you call gfs.createReadStream()? Perhaps there's something happening at the database level, access permissions/etc?

Comment: well , i dont think so as it wont get to this part, it invoke the `res.send` and end the function.

Comment: When you are testing it are you sure you are using a POST request?  Do you have any other handlers for the '/' route?

Comment: I tried using mLab, Its working fine with same code snippet which you used https://pastebin.com/raw/N1qEB4q2. Are you writing and reading from same DB ? Post you full code write and read.